# How to update a column with a date in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update a specific column with the current date. This is my query:

```
update  a
set a.x_date =(select CAST(sysdate AS DATE)as f from dual)
from RIM I 
JOIN INV P ON P.ID = I.PK_ID
JOIN ODF a ON a.ID = I.ID  
JOIN SRM R ON R.USER_ID = I.ASSIGNED_TO 
WHERE I.TYPE_CODE = 'ISSUE'  
AND I.ID = 2222;
```

I get this error message: "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Why  do you tag `mysql` if it's an Oracle quetsion? `set a.x_date = TRUNC(sysdate)`

Comment: `set a.x_date = sysdate` will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle does not allow `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`.  You can use conditions in the `WHERE` instead:

```
update odf
    set x_date = sysdate
    where exists (select 1
                  from RIM I join
                       INV P
                       on P.ID = I.PK_ID join
                       SRM R
                       on R.USER_ID = I.ASSIGNED_TO 
                  where I.TYPE_CODE = 'ISSUE' AND I.ID = 2222 and
                        I.ID = odf.ID
                 );
```

There is no reason to case `sysdate` to a date.

Answer (score 0):

```
update  a
set a.x_date =SYSDATE
from RIM I 
JOIN INV P ON P.ID = I.PK_ID
JOIN ODF a ON a.ID = I.ID  
JOIN SRM R ON R.USER_ID = I.ASSIGNED_TO 
WHERE I.TYPE_CODE = 'ISSUE'  
AND I.ID = 2222;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Please explain how your answer solves the problem, it will help everyone understand your solution with more clarity and for future reference.